# Ionic Speech Recognition - run time error Object(...) is not a function at hasPermission

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, speech-recognition

I'm trying to implement a simple speech recognition service (separately for now, to add it eventually in a bigger app).

I'm getting a weird run-time error, that I couldn't get any answer to it online or in documentation.

here's the code....

*app.module.ts*

```
import { SpeechRecognition } from '@ionic-native/speech-recognition/ngx';
.....
providers: [
StatusBar,
SplashScreen,
SpeechRecognition,
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}]
```

*home.ts*

```
import { SpeechRecognition } from '@ionic-native/speech-recognition/ngx';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
......
constructor (private sr: SpeechRecognition, private alertCtrl: AlertController)
......
ngonInit() {
try {
      this.sr.hasPermission().then((permission: boolean) => {
        if(!permission) {
          this.sr.requestPermission().then(
            () => console.log("Granted"),
            () => console.log("Denied")
          );
        }
      });
    }
    catch(err) {
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: "x_x",
        message: "Opps! couldn't get permission!",
        buttons: [{
          text: "cancel",
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {}
        }]
      });
      console.log(err);   //ERROR LOGGED
      alert.present();
    }
}

start() {
    try {
      this.sr.startListening().subscribe((matches: Array<string>) => {
        console.log(matches);
        this.msg= matches[0];
      });
    }
    catch(err) {
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: "x_x",
        message: "Opps! something is wrong!",
        buttons: [{
          text: "cancel",
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {}
        }]
      });
      console.log(err);    // ERROR LOGGED if ngOnInit kept empty
      alert.present();
    }
  }
```

with a simple HTML button to invoke start() & print whatever is getting matched by the recognizer.

Just in case this is a compatibility issue, I'm using

> > @ionic-native/speech-recognition": "^5.0.0"
> >
> > cordova-plugin-speechrecognition": "1.2.0"

The error I'm getting is always

> TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at SpeechRecognition.hasPermission

needless to say, If i comment out the content of ngOnInit, the error will change to startListening() is not a function.

P.S. This is my first question here at StackOverFlow, hopefully I provided enough info about the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to put it inside `platform.ready().then(...)`? That often solves all cordova plugin issues :D

Comment: @AJT_82 I haven't tried it before. I just did and it threw the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm... let me setup a project real quick and see if I can reproduce issue.

Comment: Cool... Thank you so much :)

Comment: Sorry, works just fine for me... You are running on device, right? Stupid question, I know, but need to make sure :D

Comment: ...and you are running ionic 4, right?

Comment: Hmm... I am testing on a device yes.
however, I'm running
_Ionic cli - 4.5.0_

_Ionic framework 3.9.9_

_app-scripts: 3.2.1_

Comment: you are running ionic 3, you have version mismatches. All cordova plugin imports that end with `/ngx` are for ionic 4. You need to downgrade plugin, npm to match ionic 3 version. Or then update to ionic 4 ;)

Comment: You are Correct... it was a compatibility issue.


- Ionic 4 ran "@ionic-native/speech-recognition": "^5.0.0"  (with /ngx import)


- Ionic 3 ran "@ionic-native/speech-recognition": "^4.15.0" (without /ngx import)

> Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As expected, it was a compatibility (version) issue.

> Ionic 3 will run speech-recognition up to: "^4.20.0"

```
/> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-speechrecognition@4.20.0
/> npm install --save @ionic-native/speech-recognition@4.20.0

import { SpeechRecognition } from '@ionic-native/speech-recognition';
```

> Ionic 4 will run speech-recognition up-to: "^5.0.0"  (latest at the time of writing)

```
/> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-speechrecognition
/> npm install @ionic-native/speech-recognition

import { SpeechRecognition } from '@ionic-native/speech-recognition/ngx';
```

P.S. You can't test that functionality on browser. (since this is a cordova plugin).

***Credits to "AJT_82" for pointing this out in the comments.***